# How to make recurrent list of lists with while-loop

Tags: python, while-loop, windowing

I have a file with the format `turn_index \t sentence \t metadata` and looks like this, where the length of dialogues (i.e. turns) is variable:

> 0 hello metadata1
> 1 hi! metadata2
> 0 hi there metadata3
> 1 how are you? metadata4
> 2 very well meta5
> 3 I'm so busy today meta6

I would like to group two turns in a list, and group all same-dialogue lists in big list:
`[["hello", "hi!"]]`
`[["hi there", "how are you?"], ["how are you?", "very well"]["very well", "I'm so busy today"]]`
My attempt at windowing the sentences two at a time is not working, and I can't even begin figure out how to group per dialogue. My code is the following:

```
turns = data.readlines()
window_size = 2
i = 0
j = 0
dialogue = []
while i < len(turns) - window_size + 1:
   restart = False
   dialogue=[]
   for turn in turns:
       sec = turn.rstrip().split("\t")
       double_sent = [sec[0], sec[1]]
       i += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to fit the edited output. Dialogues will hold all lists of lists you mentioned.

```
dialogues = []
double_sent = []
for line1, line2 in zip(turns[:-1], turns[1:]):
    if int(line2.split('\t')[0])-int(line1.split('\t')[0]) == 1:
        double_sent.append([line1.split('\t')[1], line2.split('\t')[1]])
    else:
        dialogues.append(double_sent)
        double_sent = []
dialogues.append(double_sent.copy())
```

Here

```
zip(turns[:-1], turns[1:])
```

is is a neat expression to always select two subsequent elements of something. This is definitely something useful to remember.

The next line

```
if int(line2.split('\t')[0])-int(line1.split('\t')[0]) == 1
```

checks whether the turn numbering of the selected lines are following each other. This condition will fail only if you have a switch back to 0, which indicates that a dialogue is finished and can be appended to the dialogues list. If there is an error in the numbering this will give a wrong output.

```
# Output
>>> dialogues
>>> [[['hello', 'hi!']], [['hi there', 'how are you?'], ['how are you?', 'very well'], ['very well', "I'm so busy today"]]]
```

Comment: This is almost what I need, but I didn't explain myself well. I've edited the output I need, I hope it's clearer! (Basically there are going to be many lists of lists, not just one, as many as the dialogues are, which is signaled by the turn_index becoming 0)

Comment: I updated the code to meet your use case.

Comment: Thanks so much!! especially for the explanation, I appreciate it immensely because I'm quite new to coding and trying to learn as much as possible